# Spring Boot + Swagger + custom swagger-ui.html

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I've got problems migrating a war application to a spring boot jar application.

I'm using spring boot 1.4.1 and swagger 2.6.0.

To customize swagger ui in a war you have to put a custom swagger-ui.html to /webapp directory. In spring boot it is not recommend to use the webapp directory because it does not work in a bundled jar. But putting a custom swagger-ui.html to /resources/static will be ignored by swagger.

Is there any simple solution (instead of adding the whole swagger distribution to my application)?

My custom swagger-ui.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>API</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16"/>
<link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/typography.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/reset.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/reset.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/handlebars-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/underscore-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/highlight.7.3.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jsoneditor.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/marked.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/swagger-oauth.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<style>
    .swagger-section #header {
        background-color: #ff5722;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body class="swagger-section">
<div id='header'>
    <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
        <a id="logo" href="http://www.my-app.com">my-app.com API</a>

        <form id='api_selector'>
            <div class='input' style="display: none">
                <select id="select_baseUrl" name="select_baseUrl"/>
            </div>
            <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl"
                                  type="text"/>
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class='input'><input placeholder="Enter authorization token" id="input_apiKey" name="apiKey" type="text"/></div>
            <div class='input' style="display: none"><a id="explore" href="#" data-sw-translate>Explore</a></div>
            -->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addApiKeyAuthorization() {
        var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
        console.log("key: " + key);
        if (key && key.trim() != "") {
            var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", key, "header");
            window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("bearer", apiKeyAuth);
            //window.authorizations.add("Authorization", new ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", key, "query"));
        console.log("Set authorization token: " + key);
        }
    }
    $('#input_apiKey').change(function () {
        addApiKeyAuthorization();
    });
</script>

<div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap" data-sw-translate>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can build a war file that is both executable like a jar file and deployable into an external container and keep using webapp directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't want to release a war (only to support webapp folder). Up to now the only way seems to be adding the whole ui distribution from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist and customize it.

Comment: Why not just fork/copy springfox-swagger-ui? It's already a pre-packaged webjar.

Comment: I hopped there is such an easy way like putting a swagger-ui.html to root webapp folder.

Answer (score 13):

I have found this simple way to customize Swagger into a Spring Boot application with just two files copied from original springfox-swagger-ui

First of all i have disabled @Configuration from SwaggerConfig.java:

```
//@Configuration <-- Attention, disable Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .ignoredParameterTypes(Pageable.class)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(regex("/v1/.*"))
                .build();

    }
}
```

Then I have extended a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/doc/v1/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/doc/v1/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/doc/v1/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Then I have just copied original file swagger-ui.html into src/main/resources/doc/v1/api.html with just a simple modification.
I have substituted this line:

```
<script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

with this line:

```
<script src='js/swagger.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

This is my api.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16"/>
    <link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/typography.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/reset.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/reset.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/object-assign-pollyfill.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/handlebars-4.0.5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/lodash.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack_extended.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/jsoneditor.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/marked.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/lib/swagger-oauth.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src='js/springfox.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>

<body class="swagger-section">
<div id='header'>
    <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
        <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.io"><img class="logo__img" alt="swagger" height="30" width="30" src="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images/logo_small.png" /><span class="logo__title">swagger</span></a>
        <form id='api_selector'>
            <div class='input'>
                <select id="select_baseUrl" name="select_baseUrl"/>
            </div>
            <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text"/></div>
            <div id='auth_container'></div>
            <div class='input'><a id="explore" class="header__btn" href="#" data-sw-translate>Explore</a></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap" data-sw-translate>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

After that i have copied original springfox.js into src/main/resources/doc/v1/js/springfox.js where i have changed these lines:

```
"baseUrl": function() {
      var urlMatches = /(.*)\/swagger-ui.html.*/.exec(window.location.href);
      return urlMatches[1];
    },
```

with these lines:

```
"baseUrl": function() {
            return window.location.origin;
        },
```

This is my complete springfox.js

```
$(function() {
    var springfox = {
        "baseUrl": function() {
            return window.location.origin;
        },
        "securityConfig": function(cb) {
            $.getJSON(this.baseUrl() + "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", function(data) {
                cb(data);
            });
        },
        "uiConfig": function(cb) {
            $.getJSON(this.baseUrl() + "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", function(data) {
                cb(data);
            });
        }
    };
    window.springfox = springfox;
    window.oAuthRedirectUrl = springfox.baseUrl() + '/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/o2c.html';

    window.springfox.uiConfig(function(data) {
        window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
            validatorUrl: data.validatorUrl,
            supportedSubmitMethods: data.supportedSubmitMethods || ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
            docExpansion: data.docExpansion || 'none',
            jsonEditor: JSON.parse(data.jsonEditor) || false,
            apisSorter: data.apisSorter || 'alpha',
            defaultModelRendering: data.defaultModelRendering || 'schema',
            showRequestHeaders: data.showRequestHeaders || true,
            timeout: data.requestTimeout,
            onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi) {

                initializeSpringfox();

                if (window.SwaggerTranslator) {
                    window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
                }

                $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
                    hljs.highlightBlock(e)
                });

            },
            onFailure: function(data) {
                log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
            },
        });

        initializeBaseUrl();

        function addApiKeyAuthorization(security) {
            var apiKeyVehicle = security.apiKeyVehicle || 'query';
            var apiKeyName = security.apiKeyName || 'api_key';
            var apiKey = security.apiKey || '';
            if (apiKey && apiKey.trim() != "") {
                var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization(apiKeyName, apiKey, apiKeyVehicle);
                window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add(apiKeyName, apiKeyAuth);
                log("added key " + apiKey);
            }
        }

        function log() {
            if ('console' in window) {
                console.log.apply(console, arguments);
            }
        }

        function oAuthIsDefined(security) {
            return security.clientId
                && security.clientSecret
                && security.appName
                && security.realm;
        }

        function initializeSpringfox() {
            var security = {};
            window.springfox.securityConfig(function(data) {
                security = data;
                addApiKeyAuthorization(security);
                if (typeof initOAuth == "function" && oAuthIsDefined(security)) {
                    initOAuth(security);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#select_baseUrl').change(function() {
        window.swaggerUi.headerView.trigger('update-swagger-ui', {
            url: $('#select_baseUrl').val()
        });
    });

    function maybePrefix(location, withRelativePath) {
        var pat = /^https?:\/\//i;
        if (pat.test(location)) {
            return location;
        }
        return withRelativePath + location;
    }

    function initializeBaseUrl() {
        var relativeLocation = springfox.baseUrl();

        $('#input_baseUrl').hide();

        $.getJSON(relativeLocation + "/swagger-resources", function(data) {

            var $urlDropdown = $('#select_baseUrl');
            $urlDropdown.empty();
            $.each(data, function(i, resource) {
                var option = $('<option></option>')
                    .attr("value", maybePrefix(resource.location, relativeLocation))
                    .text(resource.name + " (" + resource.location + ")");
                $urlDropdown.append(option);
            });
            $urlDropdown.change();
        });

    }

});
```

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6kRH.png)

Now you have just to run application and go to http://localhost:8080/doc/v1/api.html

Answer (score 5):

Solution if you are using **maven**:

- You should copy `swagger-ui.html` into `src/main/webapp`
- Make your editions or replace `screen.css` by your `theme.css`

Than add these code into your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.css</include>
                            <include>*.html</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: spring boot - create jars not wars

Comment: you can create a war too with Spring boot

Comment: Correct. if you have (in your pom.xml) packaging as a war, spring boot will make a WAR file